# Ubuntu 19.10 with ZFS root, why does it configure /boot/grub on ext4?

Tags: boot, grub2, root, zfs

The OS is capable of booting directly off of bpool, and documentation such as this have /boot/grub contained within bpool: 
 https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/Ubuntu-18.04-Root-on-ZFS

So I'm curious if anyone knows the reasoning behind the Ubuntu layout, and/or what the pros/cons might be of that layout.

Comment: This is a wrong place to ask it. This is the maintainers decision.